# SQL: How to check if an area is within a latitude / longitude position?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis

Basically I want to check and update a new column (**in_downtown**) in above table by using a **function** if the above data lies in following location of Downtown Seattle with these coordinates: 
Point A: ‐122.341518 47.578047 (longitude latitude)
Point B: ‐122.284355 47.578047 (longitude latitude)
Point C: ‐122.278004 47.630362 (longitude latitude)
PointD: ‐122.371559 47.630362 (longitude latitude)

If one household (hhid) is found in downtown, set the value of the new column "**in_downtown**” to be 1; otherwise, leave it as null.

Comment: these four point make the square and you want to check that points in the table are within that square or not , am i right ?

Comment: Screenshots are really hard for others to work with, please always show your data in a form that can be copied and pasted into sample tables for testing queries.

Comment: why are there four points in your description but five points in the POLYGON example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BEGIN
FOR a IN (SELECT * FROM clean.households)
LOOP
UPDATE clean.households set geom=ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || a.x_coord || ' ' || a.y_coord || ')',2285) where hhid ='a.hhid';
UPDATE clean.households set wkt = ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || a.x_coord || ' ' || a.y_coord || ')',2285),4269))where hhid='a.hhid';
RETURN NEXT a;
END LOOP;
```

This is the answer that works.
Thanks!

Comment: why? where are you setting your boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN -- (IN wkt TEXT)
DECLARE pos TEXT;
DECLARE X FLOAT;
DECLARE Y FLOAT;
DECLARE spa INT;

DECLARE TOP_EDGE FLOAT;
DECLARE BOTTOM_EDGE FLOAT;
DECLARE LEFT_EDGE FLOAT;
DECLARE RIGHT_EDGE FLOAT;

-- You'll need to set the above variables here
TOP_EDGE = 47.630362;
BOTTOM_EDGE = 47.578047;
LEFT_EDGE = -122.341518;
RIGHT_EDGE = -122.371559;
-- End bounds setup

pos = LEFT(wkt, LENGTH(wkt) - 1);
pos = RIGHT(wkt, LENGTH(wkt) - 6);
spa = INSTR(pos, ' ');

X = FLOAT(LEFT(pos, spa));
Y = FLOAT(RIGHT(pos, LENGTH(pos) - spa - 1); -- May be off by one here.

RETURN CASE WHEN (Y < TOP_EDGE AND Y > BOTTOM_EDGE 
    AND X < RIGHT_EDGE AND X > LEFT_EDGE) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END;
END
```

This should be pretty close. It could be significantly simplified if you didn't store coordinates as a text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use geometry object of polygon . you can do something like :

```
Declare @point geometry
Declare @polygon geometry
SET @point = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (-88.22 41.50000001)', 4326)
SET @polygon = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-88.2 41.5, -88.2 41.6, -88.3 41.6, -88.3 41.5, -88.2  41.5))', 4326)

Select case when @point.STIntersection(@polygon).ToString() = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY' then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: "Declare @point" ... what language is that? You seem to be using PostGIS functions, but what's with the `DECLARE` and `SET` stuff?